# Создание выпадающего checkbox списка для текстового input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо вместо обычного текстового поля сделать выпадающий список с чекбоксами. Что-то похожее на вот такой вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом, в исходном виде значения вписывались вот так:

```
<input name="name" value="val1, val3" type="text">
```

То есть, через запятую, а если еще так-то отметить первый пункт, вообще было бы прекрасно. Чтоб, например, отметив 3-е значение как первое оно встало в начало списка, а остальные уже по порядку.

Уже склепал скрипт:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Добавляем значения
  var val_data = {
    "val1": "Значение 1",
    "val2": "Значение 2",
    "val3": "Значение 3",
    "val4": "Значение 4",
    "val5": "Значение 5"
  };

  var input = $('[name="other1"]');
  
  // Создаем общий блок с классом
  var val_cont = document.createElement('div');
  $(val_cont).addClass("dropdown");

  // Создаем кнопку открытия списка и поле для записи значений
  $(val_cont).append("<a href='javascript:void(0);'><span class='open'>Выбрать значение</span><span class='value'></span></a>");

  // Создаем выпдающий список и вкладываем в общий блок
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  for (elem in val_data) {
    $(ul).append("<li><input type='checkbox' value='" + elem + "' id='" + elem + "'><label for='" + elem + "'>" + val_data[elem] + "</label></li>");
  }
  $(ul).appendTo(val_cont);
  $(ul).hide();

  // Размещаем общий блок после нужного input-а
  $(input).after(val_cont);

  // Скрываем/открываем выпадающий список
  $(".dropdown a").on('click', function() {
    $(".dropdown ul").slideToggle('fast');
  });
  
  $('.dropdown ul input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {

    var title_val = $(this).closest('.dropdown ul').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
      title = $(this).val() + ", ";

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      var html = '<span data-atr="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
      $('.value').append(html);
      $(".open").hide();
    } else {
      $('span[data-atr="' + title + '"]').remove();
    }
    
    if ($('.value').text() == "") {
      $(".open").show();
      $(input).val("");
    } else {
      $(input).val($('.value').text());
    }

  });

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}
input[type="text"] {
  display: none;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  margin: 10px auto;
  color: #333;
  min-width: 220px;
}
.dropdown a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
  padding: 12px 20px 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .95em;
  text-align: center;
}
.dropdown ul {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  background: #eee;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: .9em;
}
.dropdown ul:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 7px 6px 7px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #eeeeee transparent;
}
.dropdown ul li {
  padding: 10px 14px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
.dropdown ul li:last-child {
  border: none;
}
.dropdown input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
.dropdown label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.dropdown input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before {
  background: #666;
}
.dropdown label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 12px;
  top: -5px;
  left: 6px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #555;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.dropdown input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="other1" value="val2, val5" type="text">
```

Итак. Как видим из примера, все работает. Однако, необходимо проверить сам код скрипта, я уверен, что в нем есть косяки или его можно сократить. Самое важное, с чем справится никак не удается, в общем-то, это и есть вопрос: **Как проверить содержимое input и при совпадении значений отметить нужные пункты выпадающего списка?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Комментарии внутри кода. Вводить значения необходимо через запятую с пробелом (как в изначальном примере).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Добавляем значения
  var val_data = {
    "val1": "Значение 1",
    "val2": "Значение 2",
    "val3": "Значение 3",
    "val4": "Значение 4",
    "val5": "Значение 5"
  };

  var input = $('[name="other1"]');

  // Создаем общий блок с классом
  var val_cont = document.createElement('div');
  $(val_cont).addClass("dropdown");

  // Создаем кнопку открытия списка и поле для записи значений
  $(val_cont).append("<a href='javascript:void(0);'><span class='open'>Выбрать значение</span><span class='value'></span></a>");

  // Создаем выпдающий список и вкладываем в общий блок
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');

  for (elem in val_data) {
    $(ul).append("<li><input type='checkbox' value='" + elem + "' id='" + elem + "'><label for='" + elem + "'>" + val_data[elem] + "</label></li>");
  }
  $(ul).appendTo(val_cont);
  $(ul).hide();

  // Размещаем общий блок после нужного input-а
  $(input).after(val_cont);

  // Скрываем/открываем выпадающий список
  $(".dropdown a").on('click', function() {
    $(".dropdown ul").slideToggle('fast');
  });

  $('.dropdown ul input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
    var inputValue, innerObj = {};
    
    /* проверяем value текстового инпута. это необходимо для очистки
       от лишних запятых при удалении всех элементов и накликивания
       чекбоксов заново. если эту проверку не делать, то пустой инпут
       добавляется как пустой элемент массива */
    if(input.val()) { 
      /* если инпут не пустой, то закидываем данные из него в массив
         по разделителю ", " */
      inputValue = input.val().split(', ')
    } else {
      inputValue = []; // если пустой - присваиваем переменно пустой массив
    };
    
    /* промежуточный объект нам необходим для составления массива
       только с уникальными элементами */
    inputValue.forEach(function(item) {
      innerObj[item] = true;
    });
    
    /* если чекбокс активен — добавляем его value как ключ к объекту, 
       а если нет — удаляем этот ключ */
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      innerObj[$(this).val()] = true;
    } else {
      delete innerObj[$(this).val()];
    }
    
    inputValue = Object.keys(innerObj); // преобразуем ключи объекта в массив
    input.val(inputValue.join(', ')); // преобразуем массив в строку, разделяя элементы ", " и записываем в value инпута
        
    /*var title_val = $(this).closest('.dropdown ul').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
      title = $(this).val() + ", ";

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      var html = '<span data-atr="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
      $('.value').append(html);
      $(".open").hide();
    } else {
      $('span[data-atr="' + title + '"]').remove();
    }

    if ($('.value').text() == "") {
      $(".open").show();
      $(input).val("");
    } else {
      $(input).val($('.value').text());
    }*/
  });
  
  // новая функция

  $('.check').click(function() {
    var valuesArray = input.val().split(', '), // собираем данные из инпута в массив, разделитель ", "
        $checkboxes = $(ul).find('li input').removeClass('protected'); // удаляем со всех инпутов класс
        
    $.each(valuesArray, function(index, value) { // проходимся циклом по собранному массиву из инпутов
      $checkboxes.each(function() { // для каждого значение запускаем цикл по всем чекбоксам
        if ($(this).val() === value) { // и если value инпута равно элементу из собранного массива 
          $(this).prop('checked', true).addClass('protected'); // "чекаем" чекбокс и добавляем ему класс, чтобы на следующем условии чекбокс не стал обратно не выделенным

          return true; // уходим на следующую итерацию
        } else if ( !$(this).hasClass('protected') ) { // если у чекбокса нет класса protected
          $(this).prop('checked', false); // то снимаем выделение с чекбокса
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type=button class=check>check values</button><br>
<input name="other1" value="val2, val5" type="text">
```

Comment: Спасибо. А как быть с очисткой инпута при выборе любого значения? После нажатия на "Check values" мы видим, что выделяются два чекбокса, однако нажав на один из них или выбрав другое значение инпут очищается и необходимо снимать вручную выбранные чекбоксы и добавлять все снова. Так же, при нажатии на кнопку не изменяется "Выбрать значение". Этот блок будет видимым и хотелось бы, чтоб значения были видны.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите двойную связь вводимых данных и чекбоксов? А именно, к текущей функциональности добавить обновление введенных данных в инпуте после клика по чекбоксам?

Comment: Смотрите. Суть такая. Есть форма редактирования материала. При добавлении материала есть готовая часть, описанная мною. То есть, выпадающий список. Человек выбрал чекбоксами нужные значения в нужном порядке. Сохранил материал. Далее он открывает редактирование. По факту, значения будут вписаны в input. Но, input будет сокрыт и человек будет видеть только надпись "Выбрать значения". Хотя они в input вписаны. Нужно, чтоб после открытия редактирования, значения из input перенеслись в `.value` (это не сложно), а так же отметились в чекбоксах. Это вы уже сделали.

Comment: Но, при добавлении значения, форма не должна обновляться. Если заданы va1, val3, то при нажатии на 5-й пункт, он должен просто добавить val5, а не очищать все значения. Я сейчас добавлю стиль оформления для всей конструкции, может будет понятнее, как будет выглядеть все это дело.

Comment: Добавил в пример стили оформления. Вот [скрин](http://prnt.sc/ez0kaf) для понимания проблемы.

Comment: Скрин добавил понимания, попробую допилить )

Comment: Посмотрите счас. Я закомментировал строки, которые добавляют-удаляют значения в `.open` и `.value`, можете попробовать сами раскомментировать и посмотреть на результат, может доделать )

Comment: Я теперь совсем теряю нить понимания) Запустил выделение чекбоксов без клика на кнопку. Есть несколько проблем. **1-я**. Значения добавляются с запятыми и если последнее значение идет с запятой, то `valuesArray` не собирает его. То есть, [чекбокс не выделяется](http://prnt.sc/eztl85). **2-я**. Конечно же, перенос значений после доработки кода мне вообще не удается. Точнее, статично я смог его перенести при открытии, но вот при выборе чекбоксов данные или не меняются, или добавляются не удаляя начальные значения.

Comment: **1.** вводить значения надо разделяя их *между собой* запятой с пробелом, если вам нужна возможность зачем-то поставить запятую в конце - сделайте проверку последнего символа и удаляйте запятую или запятую+пробел
**2.** добавил комментариев, должно помочь разобраться с тем, что происходит в коде.

Comment: То есть, логика работы изменилась. Теперь мы всю работу осуществляем через массив. Сперва проверяем наличие значений в инпуте и перенос их в массив, затем проверка чекбоксов. При добавлении нового чекбокса происходит добавление значения в массив и перенос в инпут. Если все верно, остается значения из массива продублировать в .value?

Comment: Теперь закончил. Оказалось все проще чем я думал. Спасибо больше вам за помощь и отдельное спасибо за столь подробный ответ с комментариями. Подскажите, сложно ли заменить "val1" в поле `.value` на "Значение 1"? То есть, выносить туда содержимое label. [Скрин](http://prnt.sc/f09gms) для понимания.

Comment: Чтобы это реализовать, вам надо брать не `.val()` инпута, а текст лейбла, т.е. что-то вроде `var text = $(input).next().text();` и потом уже его вставлять куда надо.

Comment: О спасибо) Отмечаю, как решенный вопрос. Отличия в примере уже кому нужно допилят!

Comment: Все же возник один вопрос. Если значения задать только цифрой, например 1, 2, 3. То, порядок добавления не учитывается. То есть, жмем 2, затем один и выстраивается в 1, 2. С val1, val2, val3 такого не происходит. Почему?

Comment: Тут используется объект для составления массива только из уникальных значений, применяется метод Object.keys - он записывает значения так же, как это сделал бы цикл for..in. Остальные детали тут http://learn.javascript.ru/object-for-in#в-каком-порядке-перебираются-свойства

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), сей плагин очень меня выручил в свое время, правда я тогда хотел другую проблему решить, но и вашу он тоже должен решить)))